# CallerMemberNameAttribute and .Net 4

Tags: c#

All,

I noticed in .Net 4.5 there is a CallerMemberName attribute, which Blend specifically uses to raise a PropertyChanged event from the calling method.  My question is, since this attribute doesn't specifically exist in .Net 4.0, is it possible to somehow duplicate this behavior by creating a custom attribute?  Code samples much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you're looking for is a feature of the C# 5.0 **compiler**.

As long as you're using a compiler that supports it, you can create your own `System.ComponentModel.CallerMemberNameAttribute` and it will work fine.

Comment: Just a warning (for the OP) though: this can be problematic when upgrading framework later, especially if this is library code that might also be being used in a 4.5 project

Comment: @MarcGravell: Making it `internal` ought to solve that (I haven't tried, though)

Comment: Actually, this is for code that will be used in a .Net 4.0 project and will include XP machines when deployed.

Comment: for anyone who stumbles across this looking for how to create your own CallerMemberNameAttribute, [here's a link](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2012/06/13/using-c-5-caller-info-attributes-when-targeting-earlier-versions-of-the-net-framework/)