# Change property and INotify combined in one function

Tags: c#, reflection, caliburn.micro

I've got a function which looks similar to the `Caliburn.Micro`'s:

```
// using Caliburn.Micro;
public void ChangeProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property, ref T propertyRef, T newValue)
{
    string propertyName = property.GetMemberInfo().Name;
    T oldValue = propertyRef;
    propertyRef = newValue;
    PropertyChangeEx(this, propertyName, oldValue, newValue); // change event
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
public Property
{
    get { return property; }
    set { ChangeProperty(() => Property, ref property, value); }
}
```

and it's working fine - I don't need to pass property name as string so I can change Property's name freely.

But it would be great if I could change my call from:

```
ChangeProperty(() => Property, ref property, value);
```

to something like:

```
ChangeProperty(Property => property = value);
```

or anything that looks better.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You mean that you are not using `Caliburn.Micro`, but you want to use a function similar to their `ChangeProperty()` function in your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into CallerMemberNameAttribure which allows to easily implement OnPropertyChanged without passing property name. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx

Comment: Also note this requires .NET 4.5 or higher.

Comment: @Euphoric, indeed. But still if .net 4.5 is available it's IMHO best native solution. Using AOP framework like PostSharp can result in even better, more readable solution

Comment: @Euphoric - You don't need .NET 4.5. You need a C# 5.0 compiler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668126/callermembernameattribute-and-net-4

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
ChangeProperty(()=>Property, value);
```

Inside, you could use name convention to get field name from property name and then use reflection to set this field. But reflection may be performance hit and name convention might change. Also, in low trust environment, you can't use reflection to manipulate private fields.

Comment: you could store current values in `Dictionary<string, object>` and dont use private fields or reflection.